# Deploy a container to Cloud Run after pushing to Artifact Registry automaticlly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-artifact-registry

I want to setup a connection (without writing code) between Google Cloud Artifact Registry and Cloud Run. So on every push, I want to create/update a service on Cloud Run with the same name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The system that push the image must just after trigger the deployment of a new Cloud Run revision, with the new image. the `latest` tag if you want.

Nothing automatic is possible on a push event on Artifact registry.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are two different ways to automatically have code executed when new artifacts are uploaded to Artifact Registry:

#### First option: Cloud Function triggered by Pub/Sub

Artifact Registry publishes messages about newly inserted and deleted artifacts to the Pub/Sub topic `gcr`. Note that you might have to create this topic yourself.

To react to changes to the artifacts, you can create a Cloud Function that is triggered by messages sent to that topic. Note that you will need to filter the received messages by `attributes.action=="INSERT"` within your cloud function to only act on creation of new artifacts on not on deletion of artifacts.

More information about this is available in the GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-notifications

#### Second option: Cloud Function triggered by Eventarc

Using Eventarc, you can react to specific events such as that a docker container was uploaded to Artifact Registry. To do so, make sure to enable Data Access audit logs for Artifact Registry, because Eventarc only supports Artifact Registry events based on Audit Logs: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable

An appropriate method to react to for your use case should be `Docker-PutManifest`. See https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/event-types#artifact-registry for a full documentation of available methods.

To deploy a Cloud Function triggered by Eventarc:

```
gcloud functions deploy <YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME> \
   --gen2 \
   --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
   --trigger-event-filters="serviceName=artifactregistry.googleapis.com" \
   --trigger-event-filters="methodName=Docker-PutManifest"
...
```

See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/eventarc#deployment for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest u thinking about Container Registry , then u can connect automatic events.

Comment: Please consider providing examples of implementation and elaborate description.

Comment: @Afelaia, AFAIK, Container Registry doesn't have automatic Cloud Run services creation too. We ended up writing some code to listen to the push event, then create the service ourselves.

Comment: It can be automated if you pare it with cloudBuild , deploy in a build step after the image is pushed with a tag:latest