# How to use GCP Run services built in continuous deployment with terraforrm?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I originally deployed several GCP Run services by using a target image via terraform:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "my-run-service" {
  name     = "my-run-service"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
        containers {
            image = "us.gcr.io/project-name/image-name"
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Later on, I switched to using the integrated continuous deployment option from GCP Run, which worked seamlessly.
[image]

I was thinking upgrading my terraform file would be straightforward by comparing the required changes on the next apply, but when doing it, I can't see anything that refers the CD.

Does `google_cloud_run_service` supports this? I can't seem to find anything in the [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service).

If not, what's the alternative? So far I had to stop managing those resources from terraform, which is really not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you found a way to fix it since it is 11 months ago, but I will leave some pointers for the ones who stumble upon this question.

1. Use cloud functions as described here - [Deploy a container to Cloud Run after pushing to Artifact Registry automaticlly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672275/deploy-a-container-to-cloud-run-after-pushing-to-artifact-registry-automaticlly)
2. Trigger deploys "manually" with tags/revisions updates in terraform - https://ruanmartinelli.com/posts/terraform-cloud-run/
3. Use github actions to deploy to cloud run as well as deploying to the registry. https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun

I used solution 3 as i already use github actions to deploy to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To setup continuous deployment of a Cloud Run service via Terraform, it is a `google_cloudbuild_trigger` resource that you need to configure.

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "my-run-service-build-trigger" {
  name            = "my-run-service-build-trigger"
  location        = var.region
  service_account = google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.id

  repository_event_config {
    repository = google_cloudbuildv2_repository.my-run-service-repo.id
    push {
      branch = "main"
    }
  }

  build {
    step {
      name = "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack"
      args = [
        "build",
        "$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/${var.repo}/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA",
        "--builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1",
        "--network=cloudbuild"
      ]
      id         = "Buildpack"
      entrypoint = "pack"
      env        = ["GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT=$_ENTRYPOINT"]
    }

    step {
      name = "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
      args = [
        "push",
        "$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/${var.repo}/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA"
      ]
      id = "Push"
    }

    step {
      name = "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim"
      args = [
        "run",
        "services",
        "update",
        "$_SERVICE_NAME",
        "--image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/${var.repo}/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA",
        "--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION",
        "--quiet"
      ]
      id         = "Deploy"
      entrypoint = "gcloud"

    }

    substitutions = {
      _DEPLOY_REGION = var.region
      _AR_HOSTNAME   = "${var.region}-docker.pkg.dev"
      _SERVICE_NAME  = "${var.run_service_name}"
    }

    options {
      logging = "CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY"
    }

  }
}
```

The steps in the Cloud Build Trigger have been taken from a service I had created manually using the Cloud Run UI with extraneous configuration removed.

It assumes that you have already created a `google_cloudbuildv2_repository` resource that is connected to your repo, and that you have already deployed a `google_cloud_run_service` that this can update.